# Error when trying to purchase in any app: Error while retrieving information from server DF-BA-AH-01

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase

background: got my son a Moto 5G Plus for Christmas and he got google play credit from other family members that he now wants to use on Clash of Clans and Clash Royale but whenever he hits the purchase option in any game (also Dream League Soccer which isn't age restricted) he gets the above mentioned error message. Google Search has turned up empty on this specific error code interestingly enough.

His account is managed via Family Link if that matters but it has all permissions.

More generally speaking, is there any documentation on API error codes from Google Play so I can try to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact problem - same error code - same situation. I bought the phone for my son for Xmas blah blah blah. I just spoke to tech assistance and my problem is resolved. In my case, I’m not an android phone user (iPhone here) but I had an old google play account that I updated with payment info etc for the family account since I bought an android for my son.  Anyway, I had the payment info in the family link, my son in the family link, but I did not set up the google library (since we wouldn’t be sharing apps). As it turns out, you need to set up the library for a family link underaged member to access the payment info. That was it. Go to google.play.com - menu- account - then I don’t remember the exact steps but it was pretty self explanatory for a non tech person like me to get to the library. You choose to set it up, it pulls in your payment info and Boom! It’s fixed:)

Comment: Although you're not addressing the specific question (in default SO manner)... your answer prevents a lot of tears being shed by MSKW's kid(s) tonight/tomorrow... and hey..its 2018.. so we should accept/welcome your answer with a "HAPPY NEW YEAR" to you too!